# Which MS technologies would be suited for a data intensive application?

Tags: user-interface, programming-languages, desktop-application

I'm a junior VB.net developer with little application design knowledge. I've been reading a lot of material online regarding different design patterns, frameworks, and methodologies.  It's become a bit confusing for me.

Right now I'm trying to decide on what language would be best suited to convert an existing VB6 application (with SQL server backend.)  I need to update the UI and add more user functionality and reporting capabilities.  Initially I was thinking of using WPF and attempting the MVVM model for this big project. Reports would be generated from SSRS.

A peer suggested using ASP.net and I don't have enough experience to determine what would be better.  The senior programmers here are stuck on using VB6 and don't have any input on what to use.  They are encouraging me to use the latest technologies.

This application would be for ~20 users in a central location. Ideally I would stick to a Microsoft .net language. Current interface is similar to a datagrid table where the user would click in to see the detail of each record.  They would need to have multiple records open at any given time.

I look forward to all the advice I can get.

EDIT 2010/04/22 2:47 PM EST 
**What is your audience?** Internal clients within an intranet
**How complex are the interactions you expect to implement?** not very... displaying data from SQL server to UI. Allow user updates to said data. Typically just one user modifying a record. 
**Do you require near real-time data updates?** no 
**How often do you expect to update the application after the first release?** twice/year 
**Do you expect a well-defined set of client platforms?** Yes, windows xp environment, potentially upgrading to Win7. Currently in IE.6 moving to IE7 or 8 within a couple of months. 
**Do users need access from anywhere?** No, just from their PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would be wrong about building a simple ASP.Net application in VB.Net using Gridviews for allowing the data access and manipulation?  Seems like a simple ADO.Net trial application if you aren't familiar with it in the beginning you will be by the end.  CRUD applications are pretty common so it shouldn't be too hard to build it and then refine it as more requirements become apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a web-based solution--this eliminates alot of your potential distribution woes with multiple users.  You *could* use silverlight, but if you are locked into SSRS, this might not be the way to go.

Comment: The distribution of the application shouldn't be a problem. 20 is relatively small amount of users and they all work together. 
The only problem that we've had with smart client apps is that the users don't have admin privileges which seemed to prevent the install of the application. Copy/paste of the application files and dlls weren't a problem.  Running the installer was. So getting back to your post, web-based would eliminate distribution woes, but I wouldn't say that it's critical. Definitely a bonus for program updates/changes.

Comment: if it wasnt for the SSRS, I would say silverlight or even a browser wpf app (xbap)--no SSRS components for these technologies AFIK. I am thinking that asp.net is going to be your best bet, esp since users don't have admin.   You could try WPF using a click-once deployment.